# modulo 2 linear equation algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algorithms

Given is a set of modulo 2 linear equations. 
I'm looking for a performant algorithm that solves these linear equations. 
The `Row Reduction` to the `Row-Echelon` form is not performant enough. 
The `Row Reduction` algorithm I used uses xors of bitsets.

Comment: Where are the items you reference? is it a book, a program, a paper or something else? Are you looking for SW that does this or for algorithms you want to implement? Regards

Comment: It's a program without external references. I'm looking for an algorithm to implement myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the "most basic" standard row reduction idea that you are using in your current software, (the method we are taught in a basic linear algebra class), note that it is possible to solve a linear system aymptotically faster than that standard $O(n^3)$ time for an $n \times n$ system of equations, even over a finite field like modulo 2, using the same kind of ideas that make solving systems faster over a more standard field like the real numbers.  See for example http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/68/82/54/PDF/linalgff.pdf‎ which talks about linear algebra over finite fields, including fast row reduction for solving systems of equations (faster than basic $O(n^3)$ row reduction), with additional detail paid to issues like cache performance.  You may need to familiarize yourself with how to do the fast matrix multiplication described (which you can look up, e.g. Strassen's algorithm) since you say you want to implement this yourself though, because the methods described rely on reductions to the faster-than-naive matrix multiplication methods.  Also, since it seems you already know modulo 2 vector arithmetic can be computed 32 or 64 variables at a time using single bitwise computer operations, you'll need to check if you can still use this kind of speed up for the "faster" linear system solving algorithms in that paper, since you say you are going to implement the algorithm yourself and you are already using bitwise operations to speed up your current implementation.  If the 32 or 64 bit packing trick cannot be used in the more complicated algorithms, it may not be worth it to get the asymptotic speed-up they can provide, unless you are dealing with large enough systems of equations.

Answer (score 0):

The method of the four Russians (none of whom are Russian) may be useful here.  There is an open source library that implements it.  http://m4ri.sagemath.org